# Getting Form Document Properties from forSpreadsheet onSubmit Trigger using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I want to build an editor add for Google Form
This creates the response Google Sheet automatically

I create trigger for the form using From spreadsheet - On form submit

```
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSubmit')
    .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
```

The code is inside the Google Forms Script Editor

```
function setSettings()
{
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("NAME", "Andrew Kings");
}

function getSettings()
{
  return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("NAME");
}

function onSubmit(e)
{
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
    console.log(properties);
}
```

Since the trigger is forSpreadsheet, when the Google form is submitted the getSettings() will return {}, I believe the trigger runs on behalf of Spreadsheet
How can I associate the script to fetch Forms DocumentProperties when the onSubmit function is run

I cannot use forForm trigger since I need to access the row submission response event object of the sheet.
Is there a modification required in appscript.json manifest to associate the script to Form as well as Spreadsheets?

I am sure, some addons like Document Studio uses forSpreadsheet trigger

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Comment: What does the event object for the form look like?

Comment: It seems to me that the row submission response is either values or namedValues what else do you require?

Comment: I require rowStart and rowEnd and ColumnStart End with namedValues and Values array

Comment: Have you perform `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` on a form submit.  What does it look like?  Please post it into you question

Comment: Here's my event object for a onformSubmit trigger for a Spreadsheet `{"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"COL3":["1"],"COL1":["One"],"Col1":[""],"":["",""],"Email Address":[""],"COL2":["Email1"],"Timestamp":["7/15/2023 18:49:07"]},"range":{"columnEnd":6,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":47,"rowStart":47},"source":{},"triggerUid":"","values":["7/15/2023 18:49:07","","","One","Email1","1","",""]}` Some values have been redacted.  But the range values are there

Comment: Thank you. I understand but my main intention is to access getSettings() function from the onSubmit() which just gives empty. Since the properties are tied to form and not sheet. Makes sense?

Comment: You can tie them to user, script or document

Comment: doucment prop doesnt work, since they are tried to form. The whole question is about it. I wonder my question is poorly understood. I apologize for that